# Is it possible to update from Android 4.2 to 4.4 without disturbing the bootloader?

Tags: root-access, updates, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I have, for example, downloaded an update from android 4.1 to 4.2. All it consisted of was 10 new system apps, 5 libraries, 3 fonts, and a new bootanimation.

What I would like to know is if an update from 4.2 to 4.4 could be done as simply, like by changing out some system apps and/or libraries?

Comment: updates usually provided by manufacturer only therefore no unlocking required

Comment: AVB and dm-verity support were added in android 4.4. I don't think your device has integrity protection. You can flash custom images.

Comment: @defalt I know that the boot and recovery images require a signature but I have root rights and have previously modified /system a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KitKat has introduced [SELinux](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat#44-security) therefore you can't just update by changing out some system apps and/or libraries.

Nevertheless, while this is a broad statement you may succeed for updating single apk files.